# Failed to delete a just created File in Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, filesystems, nio

I'm using FileSystem to modify a properties file inside a zip file

```
public boolean processZip()
{
    boolean wasModified = false;
    Path zipFilePath = Paths.get(this.getZipFileName());

    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null))
    {
        Logger.info("Processing zip: #0",
            this.getZipFileName());

        Path source = fs.getPath(
            "/some/path/some.properties");

        // Delete old properties file.
        Files.delete(source);
        this.createPropertiesFile(source);
        wasModified = true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFileException e)
    {
        Logger.info("Properties file not found.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.error("There was an error updating the properties in zip: " +
                this.getZipFileName(),
            e);
    }

    return wasModified;
}

protected void createPropertiesFile(Path dst) throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(dst))))
    {
        bw.write(this.getProperties().getValues());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.error("There was an error creating the properties in zip: " +
                this.getInputJarFileName(),
            e);
    }
}
```

But every now and then it fails on windows with the following stacktrace:

```
ERROR: There was an error updating the properties in zip: C:\Apps\Test\some.zip
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Apps\Test\some.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.sync(ZipFileSystem.java:1294)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:277)
```

The thing is, that file gets copied by an earlier process (the process has ended when the zip file is modified). So I don't know what can be using that file in windows. At first I thought maybe the antivirus but it happens even with the antivirus off.

I'm not sure if there is something else that I can do to prevent this. It is not as frequent but every now and then it happens.

It has admin rights, I have tried exploding the zip, modify the file and zip it back. That only made the issue more frequent. I have tried also Apache commons FileUtils.forceDelete(file).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please try to find if your file is locked  by another process for check this link
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/resource-monitor-find-process-locked-file-windows-7/

Comment: how you create this file ? is by java? if yes did you flushed and closed the writer?

Comment: The file is copied and paste by another process, no java.

Comment: The `delete()` is pointless here. `Files.newOutputStream(...)` will cause the file to be deleted and recreated if it already exists, and will throw an appropriate `IOException` if that isn't possible. Don't keep a dog and bark yourself.